# split string in two on given index and return both parts

Tags: javascript

I have a string that I need to split on a given index and then return both parts, seperated by a comma. For example:

```
string: 8211 = 8,211
        98700 = 98,700
```

So I need to be able to split the string on any given index and then return both halves of the string. Built in methods seem to perform the split but only return one part of the split.

string.slice only return extracted part of the string.
string.split only allows you to split on character not index
string.substring does what I need but only returns the substring
string.substr very similar - still only returns the substring

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: `split()` returns an array of strings, as you undoubtedly know. Please include the code that doesn't seem to work for you.

Comment: Isn't this just thousand separator?

Comment: Do you really want to split, or just insert the thousands separator. If it’s only the latter, you could try this: `var n='1234567890';
alert(n.replace(/[0-9](?=(?:[0-9]{3})+(?![0-9]))/g,'$&,'));`. Ref: _https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch06s12.html_

Comment: please upvote: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/3014

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Try this

```js
function split_at_index(value, index)
{
 return value.substring(0, index) + "," + value.substring(index);
}

console.log(split_at_index('3123124', 2));
```

Comment: The question asked for 2 parts. Shouldn’t you return `[value.substring(0, index) ,value.substring(index)]`?

Answer (score 80):

ES6 1-liner

```js
// :: splitAt = (number, any[] | string) => [any[] | string, any[] | string]
const splitAt = (index, xs) => [xs.slice(0, index), xs.slice(index)]

console.log(
  splitAt(1, 'foo'), // ["f", "oo"]
  splitAt(2, [1, 2, 3, 4]) // [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
)
```

Comment: Why the preference for currying two functions instead of just having one function that accepts two parameters?

Comment: @Andris that's not needed at all. I've updated the example without currying

Comment: Great Answer, short and elegant. My only beef is with the later index. If you want it to work the same as the normal `.split()` you need to add one. This is also an issue with your example because you're typically not splitting a string like `foo`, you're splitting a string like `'one,two,three'.split(',')`.

Answer (score 18):

You can easily expand it to split on multiple indexes, and to take an array or string

```
const splitOn = (slicable, ...indices) =>
  [0, ...indices].map((n, i, m) => slicable.slice(n, m[i + 1]));

splitOn('foo', 1);
// ["f", "oo"]

splitOn([1, 2, 3, 4], 2);
// [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

splitOn('fooBAr', 1, 4);
//  ["f", "ooB", "Ar"]
```

lodash issue tracker: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/3014

Typescript:

```
const splitOn: {
  <T = string>(s: T, ...i: number[]): T[];
  <T extends any[]>(s: T, ...i: number[]): T[];
} = <T>(slicable: string | T[], ...indices: number[]) =>
  [0, ...indices].map((n, i, m) => slicable.slice(n, m[i + 1]));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use number formatter JS available at

https://code.google.com/p/javascript-number-formatter/

[Format options](http://www.integraxor.com/developer/codes/js-formatter/format-sample.htm)

http://jsfiddle.net/chauhangs/hUE3h/

```
  format("##,###.", 98700)
  format("#,###.", 8211)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?...

```
 function stringConverter(varString, varCommaPosition)
 {
   var stringArray = varString.split("");
   var outputString = '';
   for(var i=0;i<stringArray.length;i++)
   {
     if(i == varCommaPosition)
      {
        outputString = outputString + ',';
      }

     outputString = outputString + stringArray[i];
   }  

   return outputString;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this.
https://jsfiddle.net/Devashish2910/8hbosLj3/1/#&togetherjs=iugeGcColp

```
var str, result;
str = prompt("Enter Any Number");

var valueSplit = function (value, length) {
    if (length < 7) {
        var index = length - 3;
        return str.slice(0, index) + ',' + str.slice(index);
    }
    else if (length < 10 && length > 6) {
        var index1, index2;
        index1 = length - 6;
        index2 = length - 3;
        return str.slice(0,index1) + "," + str.slice(index1,index2) + "," + str.slice(index2);
    }
}

result = valueSplit(str, str.length);
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If code elegance ranks higher than the performance hit of regex, then

```
'1234567'.match(/^(.*)(.{3})/).slice(1).join(',')
=> "1234,567"
```

There's a lot of room to further modify the regex to be more precise.

If `join()` doesn't work then you might need to use `map` with a closure, at which point the other answers here may be less bytes and line noise.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    function splitAt(str, index) {
       const fst = [...str];    //convert string into char array
       const snd = fst.splice(index); //calc snd element while changing fst
       return [fst.join(''), snd.join('')]; //join char arrays for each tuple item
    }

   console.log(splitAt("12345", 2)); // ["12", "345"]
```

Comment: how does this perform if the string is very long?

Answer (score 0):

```
function splitText(value, index) {
  if (value.length < index) {return value;} 
  return [value.substring(0, index)].concat(splitText(value.substring(index), index));
}
console.log(splitText('this is a testing peace of text',10));
// ["this is a ", "testing pe", "ace of tex", "t"]
```

For those who want to split a text into array using the index.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a really hacky one-liner using regular expressions and interpolated strings...

```js
const splitString = (value, idx) => value.split(new RegExp(`(?<=^.{${idx}})`));
console.log(splitString('abcdefgh', 5));
```

This code says split the string by replacing the value returned in the regex.  The regex returns a position, not a character, so we don't lose in characters in the initial string.  The way it does this is finding the position, via a look-behind and the `^` anchor, where there were `index` characters from the start of the string.

---

To solve your proposed problem of adding commas every third position from the end, the regex would be slightly different and we'd use replace rather than split.

```js
const values = [ 8211, 98700, 1234567890 ];
const addCommas = (value, idx) => value.replace(new RegExp(`(?=(.{${idx}})+$)`, 'g'), ',');

console.log(values.map(v => addCommas(v.toString(), 3)));
```

Here we find the `idx`th position from the end by using a look-ahead and the `$` anchor, but we also capture any number of those sets of positions from the end.  Then we replace the position with a comma.  We use the `g` flag (global) so it replaces every occurrence, not just the first found.