# How to divide or split string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this string :

```
name="listLongueurs";
```

Using JavaScript, what is the fastest way to parse this into :

```
var list = "list";
var Longueurs= "Longueurs";
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: What is the criteria? Split it before the first capital letter?

Comment: @brittenb How is that relevant? There's no delimiter.

Comment: @Barmar If you read it, you'd see under `Parameters` that he split method treats the separator as a regular expression, allowing the OP to write their own rules on how to split.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [split string in two on given index and return both parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441770/split-string-in-two-on-given-index-and-return-both-parts)

Comment: chevybow yeah its duplicate, i think its the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string by capital letter:

```js
var name="listLongueurs";
var nameArr = name.split(/(?=[A-Z])/);
var list = nameArr[0];
var Longueurs= nameArr[1];
console.log(list);
console.log(Longueurs);
```

Answer (score 1):

To add on to Mamun's answer, you can make use of ES6 destructuring to do it more concisely:

```
let list, Longueurs;
[list, Longueurs] = name.split(/(?=[A-Z])/);
```

Answer (score 0):

we use directly the method split like this :

```
mystring.split('')
```

it will give us an array of alphabets of  this string

Answer (score -1):

The fastest way for me is that :

```js
const name = "listLongueurs".split('L').join(' L');
```

Comment: Your solution only works on that one specific example, which is likely just a minimal, reproducible example used to demonstrate the problem OP is trying to solve. Meaning that your solution doesn't work outside of the example, and is therefore not a solution.

Comment: Actually, this is exactly what was asked for.  While I agree that it is *likely* that an answer related to capitalization is important, punishing a low answer count user for providing a valid answer to the question as stated seems vindictive.

Comment: @JonSG It's not meant to be vindictive. It's meant to entice the practice of providing minimal, reproducible examples (MRE). If people come here with questions and are repeatedly told to provide MRE, but are then presented with answers that only address the MRE, they're no longer incentivized to provide such simple examples. Providing an MRE is absolutely desirable, and in my opinion those providing solutions on the site should try to incorporate that into their answer.

Comment: There's no indication of what OP wants to split on. It could be a pattern or they could just have one single string in their program that they want to split and don't know how. In this case, an MRE was not provided because the example provided gives no indication of what OP actually wants to do.