# How to split a string of sentences in half, into an array of two strings, each with as similar in length as possible?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, prototype

I have an interesting problem here. I have a couple of Javascript strings like so:

```
var a = "A few sentences. For tests. The point of these sentences is to be used as examples.";
var b = "A couple more sentences. These ones are shorter.";
var c = "Blah. Foo. Bar. Baz. Test. Test 2. Test C.";
var d = "Test sentence.";
```

I would like to extend the `string` prototype to have a method to split each string into an array of two strings, each with as similar a number of characters as mathematically possible, while also maintaining whole sentences.

The results I'd be looking for:

```
a.halve() // ["A few sentences. For tests.", "The point of these sentences is to be used as examples."]
b.halve() // ["A couple more sentences.", "These ones are shorter."]
c.halve() // ["Blah. Foo. Bar. Baz.", "Test. Test 2. Test C."]
d.halve() // ["Test sentence.", ""]
```

If I do `a.length / 2`, I get the ideal target length of the two strings... I'm just having a hard time `split`'ing and `join`ing them in the right order.

Comment: `split()` is for splitting on a delimiter character, not a position. Use `substr()`.

Comment: Why is the second string in `d.halve()` empty? Shouldn't it be `["Test se", "ntence."]`?

Comment: It seems like you're restricted to split only at the end of a sentence, but that's not stated in the question.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I wasn't clear at first. I'd like to maintain whole sentences across this split. That's where I'm stuck. I've tried a few variations on `split`ing the string on `"."` and re-assembling...

Comment: You can't use `split()` for this. Calculate the mid-point, then search for the nearest `.` to that. Then use `substr()`.

Comment: Do you also have to allow `?` and `!` as sentence ends? What about quotations, like `He said, "Help!" I said "I'm coming."`

Comment: Good question. In the context I'm using, there will only be periods.

Comment: Then just write a loop that starts at the mid point, and searches forward and backward for a `.`. When it finds the character, it returns the two substrings as an array.

Comment: That's a good place to start. I'll give that a try, thank you.

Comment: Can someone try a regex based solution here?

Comment: @xd1936 when you have a chance take a look at the solution I provided. It seems if I understood your requirements correctly this should be solved somewhat simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution :)

```
Reflect.set(String.prototype, 'halve', function(){
  let mid = Math.floor(this.length/2)
  let i = mid - 1, j = mid, sep = mid
  while(j<this.length) {
    if(this[i]==='.') { sep = i + 1; break }
    if(this[j]==='.') { sep = j + 1; break }
    i--
    j++
  }
  return [this.slice(0,sep), this.slice(sep)]
})

var a = "A few sentences. For tests. The point of these sentences is to be used as examples.";
var b = "A couple more sentences. These ones are shorter.";
var c = "Blah. Foo. Bar. Baz. Test. Test 2. Test C.";
var d = "Test sentence.";

console.log(a.halve()) // ["A few sentences. For tests.", "The point of these sentences is to be used as examples."]
console.log(b.halve()) // ["A couple more sentences.", "These ones are shorter."]
console.log(c.halve()) // ["Blah. Foo. Bar. Baz.", "Test. Test 2. Test C."]
console.log(d.halve()) // ["Test sentence.", ""]
```

Comment: Incredibly efficient, concise, and smart. Plus, I've never heard of the Javascript `Reflect` object! So thanks for that too!

Answer (score 2):

First split everything into sentences. Then find the best position and join again.

```js
var a = "A few sentences. For tests. The point of these sentences is to be used as examples.";
var b = "A couple more sentences. These ones are shorter.";
var c = "Blah. Foo. Bar. Baz. Test. Test 2. Test C.";
var d = "Test sentence.";

String.prototype.halve = function() {
  const ideaLength = this.length / 2;
  const sentences = this.split('.').map(it => it.trim()).filter(it => it != '');
  let current = sentences[0].length + 1;
  let min = Math.abs(current - ideaLength);
  let minPosition = 0;

  for (let i = 1; i < sentences.length; i++) {
    current = current + 2 + sentences[i].length;
    const different = Math.abs(ideaLength - current);
    
    if (different < min) {
      min = different;
      minPosition = i;
    }
  }
  
  const first = sentences.slice(0, minPosition + 1).join('. ') + ".";
  const second = sentences.slice(minPosition + 1).join('. ') + ".";
  
  return [first, second === "." ? "" : second];
}

console.log(a.halve());
console.log(b.halve());
console.log(c.halve());
console.log(d.halve());
```

Comment: Absolute perfection. I was halfway through my own implementation that wasn't nearly as elegant as this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved via figuring out where the middle is via [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf):

```js
var a = "A few sentences. For tests. The point of these sentences is to be used as examples.";
var b = "A couple more sentences. These ones are shorter.";
var c = "Blah. Foo. Bar. Baz. Test. Test 2. Test C.";
var d = "Test sentence.";
var e = "A. B. C. D. E. F. G. H. The point of these sentences is to be used as examples."
var f = "The point of these sentences is to be used as examples. A. B. C. D. E. F. G. H."

const half = str => {
  let middle = Math.floor(str.length / 2)
  let nextDot = str.lastIndexOf('.', middle)
  nextDot = nextDot <= 0 ? str.indexOf('.', middle)+1 : nextDot+1
  return [str.substr(0, nextDot), str.substr(nextDot, str.length).trim()]
}

console.log(half(a))
console.log(half(b))
console.log(half(c))
console.log(half(d))
console.log(half(e))
console.log(half(f))
```

The idea is to use a combination of `lastIndexOf` and `indexOf` in order to find out in which direction you need to go in terms of the middle position. Once you get that middle then it is just using `substr` to get the pieces.

Comment: An easy-to-follow and interesting approach! This doesn't split in half _based on character length of the strings_ though. It works great for an exact splitting up on the _number of sentences_, but if I were to have `var e = "A. B. C. D. E. F. G. H. The point of these sentences is to be used as examples."`, it would return `"A. B. C. D. E"` and `"F. G. H. The point of these sentences is to be used as examples."`, instead of `"A. B. C. D. E. F. G. H."` and `"The point of these sentences is to be used as examples."`. Cheers :)

Comment: Updated with even simpler implementation. Cheers.

Comment: This is simple and brilliant. Excellent work. Because it starts halfway through the string and only searches in one direction, `var e = "The point of these sentences is to be used as examples. A. B. C. D. E. F. G. H."` breaks it ;)

Comment: :) no worries you just use `indexOf` when `lastIndexOf` does not find anything. Updated :).

Answer (score 0):

Below also gets the job done. It will split the sentence into an array based on when there is a " ". Using that new array, you can use Math.floor() to get the middle of the array and round it down. Some conditions then will then sort things.

```
var a = "A few sentences. For tests. The point of these sentences is to be used as examples.";
var b = "A couple more sentences. These ones are shorter.";
var c = "Blah. Foo. Bar. Baz. Test. Test 2. Test C.";
var d = "Test sentence.";

function splitString(str){
    var workSplit = str.split(" ");
    var midPoint = Math.floor(workSplit.length / 2);
    var result = [[],[]];
    for(var char in workSplit){
        if(char < midPoint){
            result[0].push(workSplit[char])
        } else {
            result[1].push(workSplit[char]);
        }
    }
    return [result[0].join(" "), result[1].join(" ")]
}

console.log(splitString(a));
console.log(splitString(b));
console.log(splitString(c));
console.log(splitString(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use this answer to find all occurences of "." in your string.

Then, find the dot that's closest to your middle, and split it there (for example, using the answer here: [split string in two on given index and return both parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441770/split-string-in-two-on-given-index-and-return-both-parts) )

Some code:

```
function splitValue(value, index) {
  return [value.substring(0, index), value.substring(index)];
}

function splitStringInTwo(str) {
  const half = Math.trunc(str.length / 2);
  let slicePoint = {position: -1, distance: 9999};

  if (str.indexOf('.')  === -1) {
    return splitValue(str, str.length / 2);
  }

  for (let i = 1; i > 0; i =  str.indexOf('.', i) + 1) {
    if (Math.abs(i - half) < slicePoint.distance) {
      slicePoint = {position: i, distance: Math.abs(i - half)}; // Distance is shrinking, save it.
    } else {
      return splitValue(str, slicePoint.position); // Distance it growing. Stop.
    }
  }


}

const myString = "Here is a first string. My second, though, is larger by a fair amount of characters. I don't want it to be split.";

console.log(splitStringInTwo(myString));
```