# Convert the string to two string by specific link

Tags: javascript

I have string like below

```
123443GH
```

I want to slice it from end to seperate into two strings

For example if my input is 2 , It must return two arrays 123443 and GH , if my input is 3 it must return 12344 and 3GH

Rightnow I use two different codes , Is there any other fastest way to do it ?

```
str.slice(0,-2)
and 
str.slice(-2)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441770/split-string-in-two-on-given-index-and-return-both-parts

Answer (score 1):

I ran this through a quick benchmark.

It looks like providing the end-index is faster than not.

See here: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/7513/0/slice-withwithout-end-index