# How can slice a string within matching characters?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

```
let str = 'axybexaseraszarasxar';
```

i want string between "a" to next "a" like 'axybexa' string is there any way to take it using substring or slice function of string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need firstly to detect where the beginning and the end of the substring you want are.

```js
let str = 'axybexaseraszarasxar';

const strBetweenMatches = (st,sep) => {
  const first = st.indexOf(sep);
  const second = st.indexOf(sep,first+1);
  if (second < first) return st.slice(first);
  return st.slice(first,second+1)
}

console.log(strBetweenMatches(str,'a')); // your desired output
console.log(strBetweenMatches(str,'j')); // no match
console.log(strBetweenMatches(str,'z')); // only one match
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the substring, you can do like this:

```
let str = 'axybexaseraszarasxar';
let subtring = str.slice(str.indexOf("axybexa") , 7)
```

If you want to get the new string after slicing off the substring:

```
let str = 'axybexaseraszarasxar';
let new_string = str.slice(7 , str.length)
```

Comment: but i want string between "a" to next "a"

Comment: Oh is that it? You havnt mentioned that in the question. I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the behaviour that you want.

But one way to do it would be to combine the search() method and the substring() method to clear your specific example.

`str.substring(str.search(wordToFind),lengthOfWord);`

However, if you want to build it more dynamically there should be some sort of indication as to why you want that specific word. If you always receive it, why even try and break it out of the string?

As an example, IF the search() method doesn't find the word, a -1 will be returned which means you can always check if it exists within the string and if it does, always use it as a separate variable.

Another inefficient way to do it would be to use a for loop and go through each letter in the string individually until you find a succession of the letters you're looking for.

Using the answer from:
[split string in two on given index and return both parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441770/split-string-in-two-on-given-index-and-return-both-parts/16441885)

You can always create a split function that allows you to always break up the string on a specific index.

`--------------------------------------------------------------`

Since the question was just changed, Malarres' answer is the one you want. Use indexOf to find the beginning and end of the substring you're after.